# Form fields and label position in Zend framework 2

Tags: forms, label, zend-framework2

I have a Zend form created using Zend\Form\Annotation. I am using following code to generate the HTML:

```
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form);
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

The problem is labels are placed just before the input text fields like this:
Label: Input text Box

I want to do like this:
Label:
Input Text Box

How can I format my labels to get my desired position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I am going to do is use individual elements print instead of using formCollection method like below:

```
<dl class="zend_form">
    <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('identity')) ?>

    <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('identity')) ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('identity')) ?></dd>

    <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('credential')) ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('credential')) ?></dd>

    <?php if ($this->redirect): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $this->redirect ?>" />
    <?php endif ?>

    <dd><?php echo $this->formButton($form->get('submit')) ?></dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just could use css:

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just give the elements an id in your annotation like @Annotation\Attributes({"id" : "id"})